# How to pass an Arraylist from First Activity to Second Activity?

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to pass an arraylist from the activity SpinPizza.java to Bill.java(using Parcelable).

Now the problem is that in the receiving activity, the arraylist which I get is modified by itself...ie. it contains only the last entered values in all its indexes...I am unable to understand the reason behind it...I am posting the relevant code below:-

SpinPizza.java

```
public class SpinPizza extends Activity{

store temp= new store();

     int i=0;

ArrayList<store> B = new ArrayList<store>();

Spinner s=null,s1=null;

EditText edittext=null;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.drop);

          //spinners n edittext instantiation

     edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button

           if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&

                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {

              // Perform action on key press 

       int n=Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());

        temp.setOrder(s.getSelectedItem().toString(), s1.getSelectedItem().toString(),n );

          B.add(temp);

                TextView objText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pl);

                TextView objText1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pl2);

              objText.setText(B.get(i).getPizzaName());

             objText1.setText(temp.getPizzaSize());

                 i++;



              Toast.makeText(SpinPizza.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              return true;

            }

            return false;

        }

    });


      Button next1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bill);  

      next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View view) {


              Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Bill.class);


                  myIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myclass",B);
                              startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

          }

      });

}

}
```

(Bill.java)

```
public class Bill extends Activity {
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.calc);
ArrayList<store> B1 = new ArrayList<store>();

store temp1=null;
Intent ii= getIntent();

    B1=ii.getParcelableArrayListExtra("myclass");


TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);

        for(int i=0;i<B1.size();i++)
        {  
            temp1=new store();
             TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
             tr.setId(100+i);
            temp1=B1.get(i);         
             tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView b = new TextView(this);
        b.setText(temp1.getPizzaName()); 
        b.setId(200+i);

        TextView b1 = new TextView(this);
        b1.setText(temp1.getPizzaSize());
        b1.setId(300+i);

       TextView b2 = new TextView(this);
       b2.setText(String.valueOf(temp1.getQuantity()));
     b2.setId(400+i);

        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(b);

        b1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(b1);

        b2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(b2);     


/* Add row to TableLayout. */
tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



}}}
```

Please help me.

**UPDATE**

@Flo I tried doing this through Application class..But now I m getting Null pointer exception.( I have mentioned below in the line where I get it)

This is my revised code.

**SpinPizza.java** -->No changes...

**MyApp.java** :

```
package com.Lak;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Application;


public class MyApp extends Application {

     ArrayList<store> B = null;

          public ArrayList<store> getState(){

            return B;
          }

        }
```

**Bill.java**

```
public class Bill extends Activity {
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.calc);
    ArrayList<store> B = new ArrayList<store>();

    store temp1=null;

    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());   
    B = appState.getState();



 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);
         /* Create a new row to be added. */


              /* Create TEXTVIEWS to be the row-content. */






            for(int i=0;i<B.size();i++)    //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
            {  
                temp1=new store();
                 TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                 tr.setId(100+i);
                temp1=B.get(i);      
                 tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                TextView b = new TextView(this);
            b.setText(temp1.getPizzaName()); 
            b.setId(200+i);


            TextView b1 = new TextView(this);
            b1.setText(temp1.getPizzaSize());
            b1.setId(300+i);

           TextView b2 = new TextView(this);
           b2.setText(String.valueOf(temp1.getQuantity()));
         b2.setId(400+i);

            b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(b);

            b1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(b1);


            b2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            tr.addView(b2);


    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
    tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     }}}
```

I think the application class is not sending the updated Arraylist... It simply send the default one..(Defined NULL) :-(

Answer (score 2):

Your `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` method should have the fully qualified class name - docs say:

> Add extended data to the intent. The
>   name must include a package prefix,
>   for example the app
>   com.android.contacts would use names
>   like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Does your `store`class (btw class names should start with an Uppercase letter) implement Parcelable? This is part of the contract of `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get you. My application lies in the package com.Lak What should I do now?  And yes...the store class implements Parcelable...:)

Comment: call putPa..("com.Lak.myclass",B)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class or an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class to pass the list to another activity. A singleton or Application class can be accessed from anywhere in your application.

Comment: @Flo: How to do that? Could u pls give me an example?

Comment: Create a class which extends the class Application. Then you have to register this class as you application class in you manifest file. No you can call getApplication() from within your activity and you'll will always get the same instance of the application class you implemented. Within this class you can do whatever you like. E.g. storing your ArrayList and retrieve it later from your other activity.

Comment: @Flo:Ok..So i think what I can do is create this application class as a subclass of SpinPizza.java and then store the arraylist in the application class...And then through getter and setter methods, retreive the arraylist in Bill.java....?? I hope I have got it..Please correct me if I m wrong.

Comment: That's partially correct. The class which extends the Application class cannot be an Activity class. As SpinPizza extends the activity class and therefore it cannot also extend the Application class. Instead, create a totally new class. Again, in you case the application class has no other job than storing the array list. Is like a container you can access from anywhere within you Android application. As you already said, you then access the array with getter and setter methods.

Comment: @Flo: Thanx for the explaination..:-) But see the arraylist B gets populated in SpinPizza.java so r u sure that the Application class will contain the updated arraylist and will pass the same??

Comment: @Flo: I have updated my code as u explained..Please go though it and tell me why I am getting the exception...

Comment: The reason for the NullPointerException is that you never pass the array list to the application class. So you application class needs a setter method for the array list. And before you switch from activity A to activity B you have to update the array list in your application class otherwise you the getter will always return null.

Comment: @Flo: Thanx a lot man... now there r no errors/exceptions...but still there is a problem..The rows r not added...even if they are, I cant see them..When I click on Bill, I just see a blank screen.:( My head is going to blast now..:(

Comment: @Flo: Ya i did...But I dont see any errors or exceptions...I just see the static row contents..ie "Pizzaname" "Pizzasize" "Quantity"....The dynamic rows are invisible.(or probably they r not getting added to the layout) :-(

Comment: Have you checked whether the objects you take from the array list contain values? E.g. when you call temp1.getPizzaName()??

Comment: No i didnt.. How do i do that?

Comment: Debug your code and set a break point where you get your item from the array list "temp1=B.get(i);" Then you'll should be able to see whether it contains values or not.

Comment: ok..see..i understood where I was faltering...I had to invoke the setter function in another activity where the arraylist is populated...And i m so stupid that I did it here and then retreived the same null arraylist....Now it shows  the rows....BUT there is still a problem..:-( All the rows are populated with the same values...ie the values entered last...

Comment: OMG I cant believe that after doing so much...I am back to the same root problem...THE ROWS ARE POPUALTED WITH THE SAME VALUES...:-(

Comment: It's hard to say where you problem is without the whole project.